# Catch repeat - letter in PHP - Regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I need to look at a string, and find - character that is used more than 1 time

$input = "stack-overflow - 2014 - new" //Contains repeated character - more than 2 times

I found all sorts of really close answers already, but not quite.
Is there a PHP regular expression to catch this case? (I have a basic regexp knowledge but this is too much for me)

```
$regex=' '; //// that what i need
if (preg_match('/(\w)\1{5,}/', $input)) {
 # Successful match
} else {
 # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not the best choice to count the occurrence in a string. For PHP, there exists a method called [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr-count.php)

e.g.

```
$s = 'stack-overflow - 2014 - new';
if (substr_count($s, '-') >= 2) {
    // at least 2 times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to match multiple hyphen characters (`-`) with RegEx? If so, this expression will do the trick:

```
/-+/
```

---

`/` = delimiter

`-` = match the hyphen character

`+` = match multiple occurrences of the preceding character